# How assign MojoX::Redis result to variable?

Tags: perl, asynchronous, redis, mojolicious

I try to work with [MojoX::Redis](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MojoX%3a%3aRedis) and I can`t understand how catch result in a variable.

In docs used "print"

```
 $redis->get(key => sub {
      my ($redis, $res) = @_;

      print "Value of ' key ' is $res->[0]\n";
  })
```

It worked, but useless.
How I can assign result to a variable in "main" program?

PS. Indeed I really don`t understand asynchronous paradigm on this part.

Answer (score 2):

The sub is called when requested data arrives. You can close anonymous sub around variable from the outside to get it assigned.

```
my $result;

$redis->get(key => sub {
    my ($redis, $res) = @_;
    $result = $res->[0];
});
```

But pay attention to that variable is filled asynchronously, so it will not be immediately available. Probably best approach is to process result within the anonymous sub.

Comment: In mojolicious I get render BEFORE data is received. It`s necessary to create IOloop, as I show under.

Answer (score 2):

I consult with author and he give me next solution :

```
my $data_out;

my $redis = $redis->ioloop(Mojo::IOLoop->new);

$redis->get( $user_query => sub {
      my ($redis, $res) = @_;

      $data_out = $res->[0];
      $redis->stop;
  });

 $redis->start;

 $self->render( text => "|$data_out|" );
```

full text in [gist](https://gist.github.com/844526)

I suppose without new ioloop Redis is "sited" on Mojolicious loop and receive data at the end only.

Comment: You probably should add `$data_out` definition above to make this answer more clear. This approach effectively makes get blocking - it waits until data are received and then stop the loop.

Comment: Thanx, fix $data_out definition. BTW, I will be use the AnyEvent::Redis. It`s seems like more clever and well-known solution, for me at the least.